# Open page with specific tab open

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

i have succesfully implemented a part of my website where a user can complete the order, however to finish the process after the user clicks submit i want them to be returned back to the page with the orders, so that they can see their order. Simple enough i know, except my orders section is part of a jquery tab, and is the third tab, so is not the tab showing when you go to the page, my question is, how can i get the user to be redirected to the page with the orders tab being open rather than the cashout tab.

Here is the code for the tab

```
<div id="tabContent">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <!--<li><a id="all" href="#all" class="all">All</a></li>-->
    <li><a href="#cashout" class="all">Cashout</a></li>
    <li><a href="#upgrade" class="survey">Upgrade</a></li>
    <li><a href="#orders" class="videos">Orders</a></li>


  </ul>


<div class="tab_container">
    <div id="cashout" class="tab_content">
          CONTENT FOR CASHOUT
    </div>
    <div id="upgrade" class="tab_content">
       <div id="upgradeLeft">
          CONTENT FOR UPGRADE


    </div>
    <div id="orders" class="tab_content">

       CONTENT FOR ORDERS THIS TAB TO BE OPENED
    </div>

</div><!--- end tab_container--->
  </div><!---end tab content--->
```

The script code for the tabs

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    //Default Action
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

The link to go to the page with order tab being open

```
include_once 'market.php';
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write a function selectTab('#tab_id')
When you redirect users to the new tab, just call javascript selectTab

```
function selectTab(id)
{
     $('#cashout').removeClass('active');
     $('#' + id).addClass('active');
}
```

for example:
when you and you return a variable that indicate selected tab

```
selectTab('#<?php echo $this->selectedTab?>');//or $_SESSION['SELECTED_TAB']
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply where would i add this code on the page i am redirecting to or the page i am redirecting from?

Comment: You can put the id of selected tab in session, set it in the source page and echo it in the target page.